# Wrapper off-center when page extends below viewport

Tags: html, css

I have a page that is centered within the browser using the following code:

```
#wrapper { margin: 0 auto; }
```

When the page does not extend past the bottom of the viewport (thus not requiring a scroll bar on the right), it is perfectly centered. But when the displayed data extends beyond the bottom of the viewport, it shifts the div about 5 pixels to the right. Has anyone else had this problem/know how to fix it?

Comment: What browser? What other code do you have? Is it because of the scrollbar?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: I've tested it on both firefox 5 and chrome and it has the same problem. If it is the scroll bar, is there any way to negate that effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DIV is still perfectly centered.  Now you are factoring in the width of the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the contents of a centered page from shifting when navigating to different pages that does not have a scrollbar:

```
body {overflow-y: scroll;}​
```